# Метод добавления в строку символа в определенную позицию

Tags: java

Я не смог найти метод, который добавляет символ в `String` на заданную позицию. Не в массив String.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Класс [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) реализует неизменяемые строки, поэтому в нём нет таких методов, которые бы модифицировали исходную строку "на месте" (не путайте с такими методами как [`String::replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) - они возвращают новый объект [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) как результат некоторой обработки исходной строки). Зато подходящие методы по типу [`insert()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#insert-int-java.lang.String-) есть в таких классах, как [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) и [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) - они реализуют *изменяемую* строку.

Простенький пример кода:

```
public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "test string";
        String new_s = (new StringBuilder(s)).insert(5, "(inserted) ").toString();
        System.out.println(new_s);
    }   
}
```